# Setting up Route for Category-based RSS Feeds

Tags: categories, routes

I think that I need to set up a few routes to handle my category based RSS feeds. I have a current url structure as follows

```
http://something.com/shows/wmr/marketing pr

http://something.com/categoryGroup/parentCategory/childCategory
```

I need rss feeds from both the parent and child categories

```
http://something.com/categoryGroup/parentCategory/feed
http://something.com/categoryGroup/parentCategory/childCategory/feed
```

The rss template i am using is stored in

```
categories/_shows.rss
```

I have munged something together in the cp routes settings but I would prefer to have this in routes.php. Having access to the parentCategory and childCategory values without doing a segments thing would be nice.

Comment: Have you tried using the URL features on the actual categories? You can provide both parent and child URL in there and point to your template

Comment: @mcclaskiem I am not sure what that would look like. I think that I still need a route to handle the incoming request and forward it to the appropriate template. http://something.com/categoryGroup/parentCategory exists but http://something.com/categoryGroup/parentCategory/feed needs a route.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think that I have figured it out. Posting here for posterity. Based on the requirement above, I put these in my routes.php file.

```
'shows\/(?P<parentSlug>[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)\/(?P<childSlug>[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)\/feed' => 'categories/_shows.rss',
```

and

```
'shows\/(?P<parentSlug>[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)\/feed' => 'categories/_shows.rss',
```

This gives me two variables. parentSlug and childSlug